# Median function in matlab not returning the correct value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having this issue where this spread of numbers is not returning the correct value in matlab.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOPRVZR_XJ-v1nEEvuMfzoJOh702A4wg/edit#gid=1868814066

`=MEDIAN (A1:A34)` is giving me `-.380905` which is correct.

```
A=[-0.264, 0.4459, -0.49781, 1.77666,-0.55638,0.87174,-0.68504,0.92835,-0.80581,-0.87505,0.39111,-0.76054,-0.68987,1.60776,-0.19637,1.13956,1.53606,-0.08254,0.12186,0.08428,0.61663,-1.47958,2.28422,-0.80891,-0.55738,0.2238,-0.93291,0.3791,-0.63074,2.14683,-1.49948,1.21954,-0.79734,-0.51303,-1.0687,-0.61345,-1.02592,-0.87653,0.444]

M = median(A)
```

Returns
`M =   -0.2640`.
I did this calculation in MATLAB which is wrong.

Edit: I figured out the calculation was actually right in excel but wrong in Matlab. It seems that Matlab only picks one of two middle numbers in an even array.

Comment: As stated in the MATLAB documentation, for your example with an even number of values, MATLAB will pick the larger of the two middle values. I believe both MEDIAN methods are acceptable (along with others), but Excel's is more commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

> Returns M = -0.2640 I did this calculation in matlab.

You've even number of values, so the median might be interpreted differently

- Excel just takes the mean of the two middle items (that's what I've seen so far in other tools too)
- matlab gives you one of the middle values, but again as there are even values, no exact middle exists

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Máté Juhász's answer, [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/median-function-d0916313-4753-414c-8537-ce85bdd967d2) is one of the remarks when using the Median function:

> If there is an even number of numbers in the set, then `MEDIAN` calculates the average of the two numbers in the middle. See the second formula in the example.

You have 34 numbers. After ordering them, the 2 numbers in the middle are `-0.49781` and `-0.264`. Their average is:

```
(-0.49781-0.264)/2=-0.380905
```

So Excel is giving the correct answer as stated on the remarks.

As @Máté Juhász said, you got only one of the middle numbers as an answer when using Matlab.

Answer (score -1):

Your example has 39 values, so, after sorting the middle one is -0.2640.
It was too bad that Matlab made such a gross mistake.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1103998)